# What is checksum and where is used?

Tags: checksum

I have a project with topic what is checksum, I would like to explain where to be focused on, and to make more attractive from others colleagues.
What checksum?

Where is used and how can I explain it with a short term?

Comment: Checksum a "short amount of bit" appending with actual data to detect error in data. You may check wiki for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checksum is a digit representing the sum of the correct digits in a piece of stored or transmitted digital data, against which later comparisons can be made to detect errors in the data.

You can refer below links for more detail:
1. http://www.online-tech-tips.com/cool-websites/what-is-checksum/

2. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/ip-header-checksum

Hope it will help you.